# Major GC count increasing

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am working on batch application which is processes millions of records.The heap looks stable for a while,later the minor.gc count remains stable and major.gc count increases.If my application takes 20 min ,more than 16 min is spent in major.gc.What would be the reason for increasing of major GC.I have memory setting of -Xmx50g -Xms10g

Comment: There is many. many GC mastering knowledge in internet, many of content google 'low latency java'

Comment: Are You speaking from programmers perspective, is it Your code, or admin/devops ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgiXKPEILoc&list=PL6BXhCeK2LtDxi9YrmAS4nzXXLEwIoC5R&index=39 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nyq4vcEB6oc&t=409s&list=PL6BXhCeK2LtDxi9YrmAS4nzXXLEwIoC5R&index=13  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6qx_zvpOyI&list=PL6BXhCeK2LtDxi9YrmAS4nzXXLEwIoC5R&index=15

Comment: Yeah its my code .I use lot of hashmap in processing.Could that be a reason